# Storage Allocation Statements in C++

Tags: c++, variables, global-variables

I was trying to identify statements where a variable can be allocated storage in C++. Until now, I have come up with:

1. Declaration Statements: statements like `int a;` with various storage, scope specifiers (`auto`, `static`, `global`).
2. Expression Statements:
   Storage on heap can be allocated using `malloc`, `new` etc. Technically though the storage for the `pointer` is allocated in its declaration. I am counting all such cases here.

   - Assignment expr with right hand side being `malloc/new/calloc` or a function call where the called function might allocate the storage.
   - Function call expr, the variable being passed by reference and it is allocated storage in the called function.

I am unable to think of any other ways but I have an inkling that there might be many more. I hope people get the idea of what I am asking for even though the question might not be phrased correctly. :)
 Any inputs welcome.

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to group allocation statements by the class of memory:

1. Static
2. Stack
3. Heap
4. Exceptions
5. Thread local (C++11 only)

All static allocations come from Declarations. Specifically note the class template instantiations. Static data fields in templates appear as one declaration, while they generate as many data fields in the data segment as there are instantiations of this template. Static objects inside the functions/methods do not have global names like `::Namesp::Class1::Class2::Smth`. Regular static objects in classes or namespaces always have such names.

Stack allocations come from declarations of local variables and params of the functions. When something is passed into the function (ref, ptr, val, etc) it is better to threat this as something that was created according to the declaration of the parameter rather than something generated dynamically.

Besides that there are temporary vars that exist during calculation of expressions and when something is returned from the function/method. They are all stack allocations.

Heap allocations are always explicit. They are created with malloc (or one of its flavors), new or new[].

Exceptions are allocated with the `throw` statement. They are implictly deleted when control exits the `catch` block. Note that if something was thrown as `Some-Class*` (i.e. as pointer), then the C++ runtime will only destroy the pointer itself, that is it will do a `no-op`. The object should be deleted by the code of the user inside the catch block this case. Otherwise this will be a vanilla `memory-leak`/

Thread local objects in the way they are declared are very similar to static. They only have multiple copies.

Comment: @Jerry: Right, malloc or one of its flavors. Different systems have slightly varying aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the response @KirillKobelev. I was actually writing a compiler pass which collects all 'allocation's of a variable given one of its uses. The pass performs a context-insensitive, interprocedural, backwards 'reaching allocations' dataflow analysis. Hence I wanted to see all statements that are possible allocations of the variable. I ignore templates, exceptions, temp vars for now to keep it simple. Thanks for pointing those out though!